# What is ?get-info=240? when passed in a web address? (.NET)

Tags: .net, url-rewriting

A number of requests on my site have ?get-info=242 at the end of the address so for example, the request could be :

http://example.com/page?get-info=242

The number seems random.  I presume they are hackbots doing that but what is that supposed to enable the hackbot to do?

All it ends up doing is to send the request to Application_Error in Global.asax to be handled there.

Is there a URL Rewrite rule I can use to remove the parameter?

Comment: you can do it in IIS manager (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) or do it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The URL after the '?' are parameters to an HTTP GET request. If your `page` is a script which accepts parameters, then this is a legal request. If not, then someone is trying to manipulate your site.